# Submit button is not working on flask form

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I've used an identical form to submit and it has worked in the past. The submit button isn't working now, so everything within the POST and validate loop is not being executed.

This is a single page webapp. This form should take 7 fields and write to the db. The app *does* properly print the records (recent_data) from the db, so the connection to the db is correct.

**Expected behavior:** This should produce a POST-GET redirect. The submit button should trigger a POST, and it should redirect to the homepage, with the form now empty.

**Current Behavior:** The submit button does not do anything.

**Reproduce:** I think this could be reproduced with the plain boilerplate flask app code added to my code here.

**Debugging:** There is no error displayed.

```
class ApplicationForm(FlaskForm):
    emp_length_cat = IntegerField(
        u'How long have you been with your employer? (1-11)',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    home_status = IntegerField(
        u'What is your housing status? (1-Rent, 2-Other, 3-Mortgage, 4-Own)',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    zip3 = IntegerField(
        u'What is the first 3 digits of your zip code?',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    total_acc = IntegerField(
        u'How many accounts have you ever had in your name?',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    annual_inc = IntegerField(
        u'What is your annual income? (no commas)',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    dti = IntegerField(
        u'What is your debt-to-income ratio? (round to 2 decimals)',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    descr = StringField(
        u'Why do you need this loan? (enter text)',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # Set form
    form = ApplicationForm(request.form)
    data = []
    # Display db connection
    with db.connect() as conn:
        recent_data = conn.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM loans_tbl " "ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5"
        ).fetchall()
        for row in recent_data:
            data.append({"id": row[0], "target": row[1], "emp_length_cat": row[2],
                         "home_status": row[3], "zip3": row[4], "total_acc": row[5],
                         "annual_inc": row[6], "dti": row[7], "descr": row[8],
                         "scores": row[9], "predict": row[10]})
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        emp_length_cat = form.emp_length_cat.data
        home_status = form.home_status.data
        zip3 = form.zip3.data
        total_acc = form.total_acc.data
        annual_inc = form.annual_inc.data
        dti = form.dti.data
        descr = form.descr.data
        with db.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute(
                """INSERT INTO
                    loans_tbl (
                        emp_length_cat,
                        home_status,
                        zip3,
                        total_acc
                        annual_inc,
                        dti,
                        descr)
                VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",
                (emp_length_cat, home_status, zip3, total_acc, annual_inc, dti, descr)
            )
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Thanks for applying')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html',
                           form=form,
                           recent_data=data)
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h4>Begin application here:</h4>
            <form method="POST" action="/index">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                {{ form.emp_length_cat.label }} {{ form.emp_length_cat(id='emp_length_cat') }} </br>
                {{ form.home_status.label }} {{ form.home_status(id='home_status') }} </br>
                {{ form.zip3.label }} {{ form.zip3(id='zip3') }} </br>
                {{ form.total_acc.label }} {{ form.total_acc(id='total_acc') }} </br>
                {{ form.annual_inc.label }} {{ form.annual_inc(id='annual_inc') }} </br>
                {{ form.dti.label }} {{ form.dti(id='dti') }} </br>
                {{ form.descr.label }} {{ form.descr(id='descr') }} </br>
                {{ form.submit() }}
            </form> 
        </div>
        <div class="form_errors">
           {{ form.errors }}
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h4>Last five loans in the db (3rd and 5th have default correctly predicted)</h4>
            {% for data in recent_data %}
            <li>
                Default flag (1 for default) {{data.target}},</br> emp_length_cat {{data.emp_length_cat}},</br> 
                home_status code {{data.home_status}},</br> first 3 of zip {{data.zip3}},</br> total accounts in
                borrower's name {{data.total_acc}},</br> annual_inc {{data.annual_inc}},</br> debt to income {{data.dti}}, </br></br>
                description field <i>{{data.descr}}</i>, </br></br> nlp score {{data.scores}},</br> prediction from model {{data.predict}}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see in HTML you have:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/index">
```

But in the Python code, there's no `@route` for `/index`

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Does it work if you change your `form` tag to POST to `/`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried, and that didn't work.